# How to use pre-populated sqlite database for android in react-native?

Tags: android, database, react-native, sqlite

where to place `.db` file ? And how to open connection for that database ? An example :

```js
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';

// open the database
const db = SQLite.openDatabase({name: 'mydb', location: '/assets/mydb.db', createFromLocation: 1});

db.transaction( (tx) => {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM user_table', [],  (tx, results) => {
    const len = results.rows.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      console.log(results.rows.item(i));
    }
  });
  
});

export default db;
```

This code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you, at the first create a file with (for example) db.js , write in this codes

> import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';

```
 const database_name = 'myDB.db', database_version = '1.0', database_displayName = 'my application Database', database_size = 200000;
```

> class Database {

```
init() {
 this.myDB = SQLite.openDatabase(
 database_name,
 database_version,
 database_displayName,
 database_size,
 this.openCB,
 this.errorCB);

 this.createTblProduct();
  }
```

> openCB = () => { console.log('Database OPEN'); };
>
> errorCB = err =>{ console.log('error: ', err); };
>
> createTblProduct = async () => {
>
> this.myDB.transaction(tnx => {
>
> tnx.executeSql(
>
> `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblProduct (
>
> Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
>
> Name TEXT NOT NULL)`,
>
> [],res => {}, err => {},
>
> );});
>
> };

```
executeQuery = async query => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.myDB.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql(
          query,
          [],
          (trans, results) => {
            resolve(results);
          },
          error => {
            reject(error);
          },
        );
      });
    });};
```

> }
>
> const db = new Database();
>
> export default db;

///
when you want to use this functions ->

```
import db from './db';
```

remember you must call init() function at first reload page

> useEffect(() => {
> db.init();
> }, []);

```
db.executeQuery("your_query")
      .then(result => {
           let arrTemp = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
          arrTemp.push(result.rows.item(i));
        }
     console.log({arrTemp});
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log({error});
       
      });
```

Comment: Thanks, I resolved it. I just imported the pre-populated db using Device File Explorer. The code above creates a db empty db if not present.